# Python Null Field

Tags: python, facebook, api

I am returning some data from the Facebook Marketing API, using Python.  Everything is working great until I return a campaign with a missing field.

For example, if the campaign that I'm returning doesn't target ads by minimum age, but my script calls the min age field.   Since the campaigns can all be different, how can I handle this in Python to not throw an exception?

Here is an example

```
print(target[TargetingSpecsField.age_min])
print(target[TargetingSpecsField.age_max])
```

Data being returned:

```
{u'age_min': 24, u'age_max': 65}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you can do

```
print(target.get(TargetingSpecsField.age_min, None))
```

which will print the value of `target[TargetingSpecsField.age_min]` if it exists otherwise it will print `None`.

Other ways include checking for the existence of the key in the dictionary and returning `None` if it doesn't exist like this:

```
if TargetingSpecsField.age_min in target:
    print(target[TargetingSpecsField.age_min])
else:
    # do something else
    print(None)
```

This allows you to perform different actions if it does or does not include the key.